# Call a C# method from JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am trying to call a c# method from javascript. I have a asp.net page which is parameteres.aspx, but at pressing the button it shows me an error 404.

This is the Method in parameters.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public void MethodSearch()
{
   //Search
   string _sEnrollmentEsiid;
   string _sEnrollmentAddress;
   string _sEnrollmentCity;
   string _sEnrollmentZipCode;
  //string _sAMS;


  //_sEsiidText
   GetDistributionPointsRequest disRequest = new GetDistributionPointsRequest();
  _sEnrollmentEsiid = disRequest.EsiID;
  _sEnrollmentAddress = disRequest.Address;
  _sEnrollmentCity = disRequest.City;
  _sEnrollmentZipCode = disRequest.Zip;
}
```

and this is the function in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testFunction() {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost:63788/parameters.aspx/MethodSearch',
                //dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#divResult").html("success");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

and here how I call the function in HTML

```
<a href class="btn btn-danger" onclick="testFunction()">Test</a>
                                            <label id="divResult"></label>
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? 
The error is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: So debug the 500 error? (I prefer using Chromes Network Tab in Dev Tools to see the actual problem)?  Nothing in your code or example gives anyone ANY ability to help you.

Comment: It shows me this: send @ jquery.js:2
p.extend.ajax @ jquery.js:2
testFunction @ default.html:1006
onclick @ default.html:632

Comment: There was actually someone which seems to have the ability to help me. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call a `[WebMethod]` on your page, the method must be marked as `static`. Of course you probably also want it do have a return value (given it's a search function) but I believe the lack of `static` is your specific problem. If there are other issues with your code, we can uncover them once it's possible to have your method called.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MethodSearch()
{


    //Search
    string _sEnrollmentEsiid;
    string _sEnrollmentAddress;
    string _sEnrollmentCity;
    string _sEnrollmentZipCode;
    //string _sAMS;


    //_sEsiidText
    GetDistributionPointsRequest disRequest = new GetDistributionPointsRequest();
    _sEnrollmentEsiid = disRequest.EsiID;
    _sEnrollmentAddress = disRequest.Address;
    _sEnrollmentCity = disRequest.City;
    _sEnrollmentZipCode = disRequest.Zip;


}
```

Comment: You are very smart. That was the problem. Thank you very much for your help. It worked perfectly.